# Voting on questions

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that we have a few questions with more answers than up votes.

Seems to me that if the question is good enough to take the time to write an answer, that it's probably also good enough to earn an up vote along with your answer.

While having good questions in beta, especially private beta, that help define the scope of the site is important, I think this concept should apply long after we we graduate from public beta.

In Meta, however, the same doesn't apply, since up/down votes don't necessarily express good/bad question so much as good/bad idea, or agreement/disagreement.

Answer (score 1):

I use upvotes to indicate that I feel that the question (or answer) is generally useful/high quality enough for the ages.  If the question isn't one that I feel will be very useful for future folks (mostly because it is too vague), but I nevertheless think I might be able to help out OP, I will try to provide an answer, but not an upvote.  I have been led to understand that that helps the site out by pushing the best questions towards the top of the search heap in google.

Comment: Encouraging new posters with either an edit suggestion, or an up-vote also helps. Experience suggests people tend to become less generous with their voting as the site matures.

Comment: Have an upvote for that comment!  I, personally, upvote a lot - Aurura and I are the top voters on the site right now :)

Comment: Your posts suggest you upvote, but this answer reads to me as encouraging the opposite.

Comment: I upvote when I feel like the question or answer adds something important to the site, I (very rarely) downvote when I feel it detracts value, but I don't vote at all if I feel neutrally about the value it brings

Comment: I basically upvote everything that it was worth the time to read. I have only cast one downvote ever, and in that case also gave a comment suggesting how the answer could be improved. The blue dot is a handy way to mark that I have already read a post.